# ¿Cómo sumar la posición de un arreglo que se encuentre en la misma posición?

Tags: python-3.x, array

Tengo este problema que tengo que hacerlo:
La cadena de tiendas “SARES” tiene sucursales en C ciudades, en cada una de esas ciudades tiene T tiendas y cada una de esas tiendas tiene N cajeros, los cuales capturan sus ventas de manera individual, hacer un programa que calcule cuánto vendió cada tienda dado la venta de cada empleado, y también determinar cuánto vendió cada ciudad, y la venta total de la tienda a nivel nacional.

Llevo hecho casi todo pero no tengo idea de cómo ir sumando las ventas por ejemplo de la primera ciudad en la primera tienda y cómo lo tengo pensado me da error al querer agregarlo a un arreglo

```
ciu = int (input("Ingrese cantidad de ciudades"))

ciudaes= []
cajeros = []
totalvtie = 0
ventatienda= []
ventaciudad= []
i = 0

for r in range(ciu):
    print("ciudad ",r+1)
    cantidad =int (input("Ingrese cantidad de tiendas"))
    ciudaes.append(cantidad)

for q in range(len(ciudaes)):
    for s in range(ciudaes[q]):
      print("Ciudad",q+1)
      print("tienda",s+1)
      cantidad =int (input("Ingrese Cantidad de cajeros"))
      cajeros.append(cantidad)

for qi in range(len(ciudaes)):
    for si in range(ciudaes[qi]):
        for pir in range(cajeros[si]):
            print("cuanto vendio el vendedor ",(pir+1),"De la tienda ",(si+1),"De la ciudad ",(qi+1))
            ventastienda = input()
            ventatienda[si]=ventastienda+ventatienda[si]
```

Me da este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kike\Desktop\Python\Casa\Ciclos\pruebas.py", line 27, in <module>
    ventatienda[si]=ventastienda+ventatienda[si]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

Te sale ese error porque `ventatienda` está vacía por lo que intentar acceder al elemento número [si] da fallo de indice fuera de rango.

prueba con

```
ventatienda.append(ventastienda)
```

Hay muchas cosas que cambiar de tu código y formas de optimizarlo de forma más "pythonica", pero poco a poco ;)